# ¿Cuáles funciones tiene "se" dentro de un análisis sintático?

Tags: sintaxis

Ahora estoy estudiando análisis sintático para el próximo día.

En ciertas frases, aparece la palabra "se". He entendido que esta palabra designa a muchas funciones en el análisis de oraciones.

Este contenido se estudia en bachiller (el año que viene) por lo que he entendido, pero me pica la curiosidad por saber qué funciones puede dar.

Gracias!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque cualquier búsqueda sencilla en Internet puede responderla. La [entrada del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas al respecto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=se) contiene información completa, detallada y bien explicada.

Comment: La entrada de la RAE está organizada por apartados. Podrías, por ejemplo, copiar en un papel los títulos de los apartados y escribir una frase de ejemplo de cada una. Si después de hacerlo aún te quedan dudas, puedes preguntar algo más concreto y la comunidad SE te responderá encantada. Pero tu pregunta tal y como está pide básicamente que te resumamos información que está al alcance de cualquiera con un ordenador, y tal no es la finalidad de esta página.

Comment: @spund3 Imposible. Es demasiado extenso y no es sencillo de explicar. Es mejor seguir la recomendación de Yay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SE Reflexivo.**

> El reflexivo significa que la misma persona que hace la acción la recibe.

`suicidarse`, `especializarse`, `arrepentirse de`, `asombrarse de`, `atreverse a`, `burlarse de`, `darse cuenta de`, `empeñarse en`, `enterarse de equivocarse`, `portarse bien / mal`, `resignarse`, `quejarse`

> Hay otros que conocemos como reflexivos pero también pueden ser
>   transitivos, es decir pasar su acción a otra cosa o persona.

`Cambiarse`, `vestirse`, `lavarse`, `cepillarse`

> Me cambio todos los días y cambio mi dinero en el banco.

`Aburrirse`, `alegrarse`, `cansarse`, `enojarse`, `divertirse`, `molestarse`, `preocuparse`, `interesarse`, `sorprenderse`, `asustarse`, `entristecerse`, `enfermarse`, `hincharse`, `mejorarse`, `curarse`, `pararse`, `sentarse`, `acostarse`, etc.

> También están los que nos indican un consumo total de algo.

`Tomarse`, `comerse`, `beberse`, `devorarse`.

Reflexive verbs are, in my opinion, the easiest `se` to grasp.  Translated to English, a sentence with a reflexive verb will have the word `self` in there somewhere, and if not, the sentence will indeed express some kind of emotion.  In English, we say that we want to `Take a bath/shower` when in Spanish you would bathe or shower yourself... or someone else even.  `Quiero ducharme` -- `I want to take a shower.`

At the bottom of the list above are some other reflexives that do not express emotion, but rather, consumption of some kind, whether it be yourself or something else, a consumption of ... all of it... as the quote says.

> nos indican un consumo total de algo

Example..

> - We're eating all of the pizza / Nos comemos la pizza
> - He drank the whole thing! / ¡Él se lo tomó!.

**SE Recíproco.**

> Implica una acción y dos personas realizándola al mismo tiempo.( Ellos= se).

`amarse`, `quererse`, `llamarse`, `verse`, `besarse`, `abrazarse`, `admirarse`, `tocarse`, `odiarse`

I would call this the opposite of a Reflexive verb.  These are personal verbs that involve another subject, as the definition suggests.

**SE Accidental.**

> Se usa para expresar la realización de una acción de manera accidental
>   o donde el sujeto no quiere asumir la responsabilidad.

`Romperse`, `perderse`, `olvidarse`, `caerse`, `quemarse`, `doblarse`, `quebrarse`, `abrirse` , `descomponerse`

In the Spanish language, for some reason, they do not accept the blame.  You don't forget your wallet, your wallet forgets you.  It's strange, but it's true.

**SE Impersonal.**

> Lo usamos cuando no sabemos o no queremos o no importa quien hace la
>   acción, sirve para expresar generalizaciones. Comúnmente aparece en la
>   tercera persona singular con verbos intransitivos sin embargo también
>   aparecen con algunos transitivos que se toman como “impersonales”.

```
Intransitivo. Se vive bien en Querétaro 
Transitivo. Se habla español en México.
```

You will often hear this usage when you are asked how to say something.

> ¿Cómo se dice ... potato... en español?`

Using English as an example you can see the trend used in this form of SE.

In English, we use "they" or "you" a lot to explain instructions, or advertisements, or, mainly, just to generalize... in some cases, "we"... as in `We sell furniture`... translated to `Se vende muebles`.

Other English examples -- in spanish.

> We speak Spanish (like the signs outside of a business)
>
> **Se habla español**
>
> You open it with a fork (instructions)
>
> **Se la abre con tenedor**
>
> They say the homework is hard (generalize)
>
> **Se dice es dificil la tarea**
>
> You don't say it like that (instructions)
>
> **No se lo dice así**

This impersonal "se" is a bit tricky to get used to.  I still use it incorrectly to this day, even after 15+ years of practice and education.

*Taken from my Advanced Spanish Manual, written by Veronica Martinez of ITESM Querétaro.*

Comment: *se habla Español* lo veo más pasivo que activo: *Spanish is spoken.* I don't agree with your last examples. We can use the reflexive passive.

Comment: I agree with @Ustanak . This is not the standard classification. Some examples are mistaken, especially with the "se reflexivo". Also, "Se accidental" is a semantic definition, not a grammatical one. I recommend you take a look at the link in the comment to see the official classification.

Comment: @Yay I wish I could endorse this answer. It's too broad and the use of *se* can even be more complicated as it looks.