# Use of "Se" for opening times

Tags: gramática

As I understand it, `se` in Spanish means oneself or yourself.

```
El museo se abre todos los días.
The museum is opened every day.
```

What is the meaning of `se` in the above sentence. I am a bit confused as to why it is necessary to indicate that museum is open. Isn't `abre` enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the impersonal.

It is like saying "the museum opens `itself` every day" meaning that an unterminated entity opens the museum given that it is not actually possible for the museum to open by itself.

It is just like in English you can say it like these:

> 1. The museum opens every day = El museo abre todos los días
> 2. The museum is opened every day = El museo se abre todos los días.

You are right, "abre" is enough just like in English "opens" is enough, however there is also the impersonal form like in example 2.

There is a great link [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/cu%C3%A1les-funciones-tiene-se-dentro-de-un-an%C3%A1lisis-sint%C3%A1tico/15972#15972) for all the "se" uses pointed out by dockeryZ, unfortunately in Spanish.

Comment: *open* can work as an adjective too if translated as the following: *El museo está abierto todos los días.*

Comment: This isn't the reflexive usage.  It's impersonal. http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/cu%C3%A1les-funciones-tiene-se-dentro-de-un-an%C3%A1lisis-sint%C3%A1tico/15972#15972

Comment: @dockeryZ. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed my answer. Great answer for all "se" uses. That question should be reopened for the sake of that answer.

Comment: I can add a couple little things — this is called "passive voice". In general transitive verbs work like this in spanish, while intransitive verbs don't need it ("me gusta el helado" => _I like ice cream_, but literally it is already _the ice cream pleases me_). And in the example given, "is opened" should still be in the present tense "is open".